# Изменение размера QWidget в зависимости от QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlabel

Пытаюсь переписать код с *Tk* на *PyQt5*

В *Tk* изначально окно меняется до нужного размера в зависимости от текст, в то время как в *PyQt5* размер каждого элемента установлен изначально фиксированный.

Идей как это исправить нет. В Интернете информации найти не получилось.

**Tk**:

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.75)
        self.root.config(background='black')

        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        root_width = self.root.winfo_width()

        center_with_offset = int((screen_width - root_width)/2)
        
        self.root.geometry('+'+str(center_with_offset)+'+0')

        self.label = Label(self.root, text="Test", font=("Consolas", 10))
        self.label.config(foreground='white')
        self.label.config(background='black')
        self.label.config(justify=LEFT)
        self.label.pack()

    def show(self):
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        root_width = self.root.winfo_width()

        center_with_offset = int((screen_width - root_width)/2)

        self.root.geometry('+'+str(center_with_offset)+'+0')
        self.root.update()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.label.config(text = text)
```

**PyQt5**:

```
class QWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.75)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: black; color: white')

        self.lbl1 = QLabel('Zetcode', self)
        self.lbl1.mouseReleaseEvent = self.print

        self.show()
    
    def print(self, *args):
        print(args)
        qApp.quit()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.lbl1.setText(text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо поместить `label` в менеджер компоновки:

```
    ...
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
    layout.addWidget(self.label, stretch=1)
    ...
```

Я также добавил `lineEdit`, чтобы можно было менять текст
и наблюдать что происходит.

Обратите внимание на некоторые другие вещи, которые я добавил:

> **`wordWrap`** : bool
>
> Это свойство содержит политику переноса слов для  label's.

> **`maximumWidth`** : int
>
> Это свойство содержит максимальную ширину виджета в пикселях.

> void QLineEdit::**`editingFinished`**()
>
> Этот сигнал излучается при нажатии клавиши `Return` или `Enter`
> или при потере фокуса при редактировании строки.

> void QWidget::**`adjustSize`**()
>
> Регулирует размер виджета, чтобы он соответствовал его содержимому.

Также я переопределил два метода `mousePressEvent` и `mouseMoveEvent`,
чтобы вы могли перетаскивать окно **`ЛКМ`**.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
                            Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.75)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #2D2424;')  

        self.label = QLabel('Zetcode', self)
        self.label.setMaximumWidth(500)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)                             # !!!
        self.label.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: #5C3D2E; 
            color: #E0C097; 
            font-size: 25px;
        ''')

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit('Hello<br>World')
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumWidth(50)                       # !!!
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: #B85C38; color: white')
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.set_text)    # !!!
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)                              # !!!
        layout.addWidget(self.label, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, stretch=0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)

    def set_text(self):  
        self.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.adjustSize()                                       # !!!
        
    # +++ vvvvvvvvvvv для перетаскивания окна ЛКМ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
            
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
    # +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> Но всё же стоило сказать, что данное окно должно просто выводить информацию на экран и не более. Т.е. просто находиться в верху экрана без возможности как-либо меняться пользователем напрямую (максимум нажатие на дабы изменить вывод на следующий)

Тогда попробуйте так:

```
import sys                                                         
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)   
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setText("<b style='color: red;'>Hello World</b>")
        self.setFont(QFont("Times", 15)) 
        self.adjustSize()
        self.setGeometry(
            QStyle.alignedRect(
                Qt.LeftToRight,
                Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop,
                self.size(),
                QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry()
            )
        )

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            qApp.quit()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Label()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, но всё же стоило сказать, что данное окно должно просто выводить информацию на экран и не более. Т.е. просто находиться в верху экрана без возможности как-либо меняться пользователем напрямую (максимум нажатие на дабы изменить вывод на следующий)

Comment: @Firec я добавил другой вариант в свой ответ, проверьте.